# What are the characters I can use in jQuery.ajax?

Tags: jquery

I am making a website that sends with jQuery.ajax a lot of information which is inside many inputs.
In order to be able to send this ajax with any character in the inputs, I want to replace the values I send to something that can be sent via ajax. So for this I need to know which characters I can send and which characters I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to care about which characters. Jquery encodes them for you. For example, if you do:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your_url",
   data: {
      name: $("#txtName").val(),
      lastName: $("#txtName").val(),
   }
});
```

`$.ajax` will urlencode your '`name`' and '`lastName`' params automagically, so you don't have to care.

Any character can be sent.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, didn't know jQuery can parse a JSON object into a POST/GET string.

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions on which characters can be sent via HTTP requests.  However, you do need to *encode* your input values.  How you do this depends on how exactly you're making the requests.  If you're doing an HTTP GET and are placing the values in the query string, you should use `encodeURIComponent`.  This is required because this isn't a valid URL:

```
/MyAjaxMethod?data=This Is a String
```

but this is:

```
/MyAjaxMethod?data=This%20Is%20a%20String
```

If you are doing an HTTP POST with form values or JSON, then jQuery will encode the data for you.

Comment: I'm using POST with JSON, but it still gives me "parsererror".

Comment: That sounds like an error with the *response* to your request.  If you use a tool like Firebug and post the content of the response, we can point out the problem.

Comment: Jquery also handles GET params encoding for you.

Comment: True, if you pass the get parameters in the data parameter.  If you're building a URL string, it won't.